# Selenium integration with Jenkins

Tags: java, github, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

i have been trying to run selenium scripts automatically from Jenkins. i have my scripts on Github and also added a plugin for Github on Jenkins. how to run those scripts from Github repository? i am new to all this so not sure what would be the next step

Answer (score 1):

Give these a look through just in case: http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/configuring-jenkins-continuous-integration-server-to-work-with-git/ and http://justinramel.com/2012/10/20/jenkins-dot-net-setting-up-your-first-job/

You'll want to select git as your VCS system, you'll want to type in the url to the repository so jenkins knows where it's pulling from (you may need to set up credentials).  From there, you'll want to execute the command that will run your java program.  I don't have access to a jenkins machine at the moment, I believe it's under Build, choose add build step.  Depending on how you want to execute your java program, you'll type the command there.  It could be a shell command, or windows batch command depending on if you're using linux or windows.

Comment: I have added git repository link(where all my selenium scripts are stored) on Jenkins. Do you know shell command to run those scripts?

Comment: Is it a jar file?  If you had the file locally, and you wanted to run it from the working directory, what command would you use?

Comment: I believe it should just be the normal command, as if you were executing the scripts from your local working directory.  When Jenkins pulls from the VCS, it puts it in a specific location, then executes the command from that same location.  Let me know if that helps!

Comment: locally i am running scripts from eclipse. So it's just a run button to play the scripts. not sure about shell commands

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna assume that you aren't packaging it into a jar file.  I believe that if you check it out with VCS you'll have to run the class from the root of the project.  Also, if you're checking out the source and not the binaries (like you should be)  You'll need to compile the source code.  I neglected to mention this, but make sure jenkins has a config in place to do periodic builds of the source.  From there, you'll want to execute the code as if you were in the project root folder.  such as: java com/project/selenium/Main.class

I hope this helps, I'm reciting this from memory...

Comment: Thanks Julian. I did some research and i think it's possible using ant too by building everything in xml file.

Comment: Depending on the structure of your project, you could use Maven as well.  That's what I used.  Maven can be real simple to use,  but it can also be hell depending on the complexity of your project.